# Javascript set text if day is equal to

Tags: javascript

My following javascript is supposed to tell my customers when they will receive their packages on a specific day, e.g. if it's sunday, we will send their package monday.

```
<script>
    function date() {
        if (new Date().getDay() == 5) {
            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "Order before <b>9pm</b> and receive your package <b>saturday</b>.";
            document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = "<span style="color:#000; background-color:#FFFF03; padding:5px;">Same as above.</span>";
        }
        if (new Date().getDay() == 6) {
            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "Order <b>now</b> and we'll send your package <b>monday</b>.";
            document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = "<span style="color:#000; background-color:#FFFF03; padding:5px;">Same as above.</span>";
        }
        if (new Date().getDay() == 0) {
            document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "Order <b>now</b> and we'll send your package <b>monday</b>.";
            document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = "<span style="color:#000; background-color:#FFFF03; padding:5px;">Same as above.</span>";
        }
    }
window.onload = date;
</script>
<span id="date"></span>

<span id="date1"></span>
```

But if i change the day's number to today, it's not working.

Comment: this only runs on window load. How are you testing this? By running on each day?!

Comment: I'm confused by the last line - `But if i change the day's number to today, it's not working.` What does this mean? How are you "changing" the day's number?

Comment: It has to check everyday though?..

Comment: Also, if you could give us a rough english translation of your text, I think it might also be clearer!

Comment: there is a error in sintax. "<span style="color:#000;. -> "<span style=\"color:#000; or '<span style="color:#000; or "<span style='color:#000;

Comment: If you look at this: "new Date().getDay() == 0" it says that when the day is "0", or sunday it will run the script inside, and today is "4", or Thursday, so i changed 0 to 4 to test if it would run.

Comment: **4** is actually Thursday... shouldn't it be **3** (Wednesday)?

Comment: @ymz its Thursday today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing stopping your code running was a syntax error caused by using double quotes within a double quoted string. Ie, in Javascript you cannot do this:

```
var myStr = "Hello "world", my name is Jamie";
```

You need to either escape the string, or use single quotes as the string container - both of these will work:

```
var myStr = 'Hello "world", my name is Jamie';
// or
var myStr = "Hello \"world\", my name is Jamie";
```

Here is your code working (having changed the "0" to a "4" to make it react to today)

```js
function date() {
  if (new Date().getDay() == 5) {
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "Bestil indtil kl. <b>21.00</b> og modtag din pakke <b>lørdag</b> til pakkeboks.";
    document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:#000; background-color:#FFFF03; padding:5px;\">Bestil indtil kl.   <b>21.00</b> og modtag din pakke <b>lørdag</b> til pakkeboks.</span>";
  }
  if (new Date().getDay() == 6) {
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "Bestil <b>nu</b> og vi afsender <b>mandag</b>.";
    document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:#000; background-color:#FFFF03; padding:5px;\">Bestil <b>nu</b> og vi afsender <b>mandag</b>.</span>";
  }
  if (new Date().getDay() == 4) {
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "Bestil <b>nu</b> og vi afsender <b>mandag</b>.";
    document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = "<span style=\"color:#000; background-color:#FFFF03; padding:5px;\">Bestil <b>nu</b> og vi afsender <b>mandag</b>.</span>";
  }
}
window.onload = date;
```

```html
<span id="date">Bestil indtil kl. <b>21:00</b> i aften og modtag din pakke <b>i morgen</b>.</span>

<span id="date1">Bestil indtil kl. <b>21:00</b> i aften og modtag din pakke <b>i morgen</b>.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `new Date().getDay()` you will get the current day and if you want to only tell customers that their package will be delivered next day then simply put  `new Date().getDay()+1` in your code ! If your query is different than i interpreted then pls do tell me !